# C++ File I/O Tab separated data

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a text file with numbers as follows:
num1 TAB num2 TAB.... num22 newline
.
.
.

I would like to read num1 check to see if it is equal to 3 and if yes copy the entire row to a new file. What is the fastest way to do this? The file is quite big 80Mb+. Also, num 1 is repetitive, i.e it goes from 0 to 3 in steps of 0.001. So I just have to read every so many steps. I am not sure how to tell the computer to a-priori skip x-lines?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need to use C++ to do this?  `"grep -P '^3\t'"` or similar would do what you want, and will be very fast.

Comment: How concerned are you about runtime performance? This is trivial to do with stdlib streams, but if you're worried about overhead then [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/).Qi is the way to go.

Comment: (Note: `grep -P` requires gnu grep)

Comment: Not really concerned about performance as I can take a walk or do something else as this runs. @therefromhere, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean the unix command line tool `grep` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep - you're just looking for lines beginning with `3<tab>`, right?

Comment: Correct, once I locate that, I'd like to copy that entire row into a separate file. The reason I asked for C++ is because the rest of my code is in C++ and I can just call this function to git-r-done. :)

Comment: Ah, if it's part of larger application, fair enough, go with C++.  If you're just looking to process a file as a standalone task though, unix command line tools like grep, sed, awk are very handy (and are available on all platforms).

Comment: -1 for driveby linking in chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you've said that runtime performance is not a primary concern, then the following is clear and concise:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

void foo(std::string const& in_fn, std::string const& out_fn)
{
    std::ifstream is(in_fn);
    std::ofstream os(out_fn);

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(is, line))
        if (line.size() && std::stoi(line) == 3)
            os << line << '\n';
}
```

(C++11 support assumed; error handling omitted for brevity.)

Comment: Thank you. Others please note that you have to enter the full path of the input and output files, i.e usage is: int main()
{
 foo("F:/Backup Drive/file_read/Debug/save_data.txt","F:/Backup Drive/file_read/Debug/sorted.txt");

}

Comment: If for some reason you want say 2.999 instead of 3, use std::stod instead of std::stoi. Tried it and it worked!

Comment: Quick question, how to obtain the previous line? Since 0 follows 3 (in my data set), I'd like to check for a 0 and store the previous line.

Comment: O.k, figured it out.     std::string line;
 std::string previous_line="4";
 while (std::getline(is, line)){
  if (line.size() && std::stod(line) == 0.0 && previous_line != "4"){
   //cout<<line<<endl; 
   os << previous_line << '\n'

Answer (score 1):

pseudo code can looks like this:

```
while (not eof) {
    fgets(...);
    find TAB symbol or end of line
    get string between two marks 
    cleain it from spaces and other unnecessary symbols
    float fval = atof(...);
    if (fval == 3) {
        write the string into new file
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I used your pseudo-code but unfortunately SE does not let me select more than one accepted answer. If there is a way to retroactively create a bounty, please let me know. I'd like to give you some of my rep.